# Excel Function Assistance

Tags: excel-formula

I have a series of alphanumeric reference numbers, and I'm trying to make a formula that displays the largest number values, so that users can enter the next number in the sequence.

Currently, the lookup values look like this:

```
[Fiscal Month][source ID][###][dual match suffix, if applicable]
```

This means it can have any of the following formats:

```
01a205, 01a205c, 01b205, 01b205c, 01c205, 01c205b, 01c205a, 01c205t, 01t205, 01t205c
```

The column values are not in order, as reference numbers are not added until a specific action is taken to which these reference numbers correspond (it is a bank reconciliation spreadsheet). However, because they all contain a sequential numeric value, I just want there to be a way to show the next value (adding a +1 at the end) so that the users can just see it and start adding values.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So in this case you would want a cell to display 205? Can it have more than 3 digits?

Comment: Ideally it would only have three digits, because each month never sees any more than 999 entries (in fact the most we've ever seen is 500)

Comment: And never less than 3? Then maybe my solution below works for you. Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. I had a stack of deadlines that suddenly dropped on my desk on Friday so I couldn't revisit this issue. I'm going to try to help today for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of digits is always 3, you can do this:

```
=MAX(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A100),0,VALUE(MID(A2:A100,4,3))))
```

Replace A100 with the proper last cell to consider from the column (I guess you need to skip the column header, otherwise you could use `A:A`). If the cell is not empty, it gets those 3 characters from the middle and finds the maximum.

If the number of digits could be other than 3, then this won't work and you will need a more complex approach. For regexes (ideal) I think you need VBA (not ideal). The other option would be to have more checks with a few `IF`.

Comment: I'll try this on Monday and let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: So the formula is presenting an value error. I think its because the Mid(A2:A100,4,3) seems to present only a VALUE error. What would be another alternative here?

Comment: Are you using an old version of Excel? Here all functions are working on a range of cells, and then `MAX` processes that output as well; maybe older versions don't support this. If you simply do `MID(cell,4,3)`, do you get the 3 digits?

Comment: Unfortunately it was that part, the MID(cell,4,3) that was presenting the #VALUE error. It's Excel 2016 so it shouldn't be too outdated (I don't think). I'm out of the office for the Thanksgiving holiday. Once I'm back I'll try again?

Comment: `MID` was introduced in Excel 2003, `=MID("apple",2,3)` returns `ppl`, it should work. What is the exact function you are trying?

Comment: Sorry for the daly. Again I was out of the office. However: that above MID formula works if you only apply it to one cell. When I use the formula and try to apply it to the whole range, it comes up with a #VALUE error. That is what I'm trying  to figure out. The range in question is G12:G1500, and it includes some blank cells.

Comment: I have Excel from Microsoft 365, I'm not sure if the range functions have been improved since. For example, if I enter `=ISBLANK(A2:A100)` in a cell, I get a list of TRUE and FALSE below, corresponding to each cell from column A. If that doesn't work for you, maybe you will need an auxiliary column which does `MID` for each row, and then use the `MAX` in a separate cell. For example, `=IF(ISBLANK(G12),0,VALUE(MID(G12,4,3)))` in `H12`, copy to the end of the table, and then `=MAX(H12:H1500)` to get the maximum.

Comment: @alandy072, still around?

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry. I had 6 deadlines due by COB yesterday, so i was busy trying to get things done on that end. As to your suggestion, I was able to find a formula that I think works: MAX(MID(LOOKUP(2,1/((COUNTIF($G$12:$G$1500,">"&$G$12:G$1500)=2)*($G$12:G$1500<>"")),$G$12:$G$1500),4,3))). This seems to do the trick! The only thing is, that, because this is used on multiple tabs, I am unsure what the "=2)*" refers to. I can understand the syntax for everything else, but not that portion. I tried using a 1 or 0, but they don't seem to work the way I need them to. Can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: It also doesn't seem to work if there are duplicate reference numbers (such as two items that, together, match together

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. That function looks too complicate to my taste, you shouldn't need to do all that. What do you get with my approach? I first want to know if your Excel supports functions with ranges. What does this do if you put it in one cell, in a separate place? `=ISBLANK(G12:G100)`

Comment: no worries! Its a hectic time for me too. The '=ISBLANK(G12:G100)' comes up with "FALSE"

Comment: In my case it returns a list of `FALSE` in that cell and the ones below (I honestly don't recall seeing that behavior in older Excels). So if yours doesn't do the same (that is, support nested range function), I think you will need the auxiliary column like I mentioned above. Unless that ugly function :P you found is better for you.

Comment: Well unfortunately adding columns to the spreadsheet is a whole other thing. #governmentbureaucracy. But the ugly formula works ONLY if the newest value is at the bottom of the column. So it isn't perfect at ALLLL. Hence why I was hoping you'd be able to assist me in figuring that out. Its not ideal, but it works at least.

Comment: Well, I've created a spreadsheet with my suggestion, saved it also in 2003 format and it still worked. So I've uploaded both [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MQJIdDniIR9Tcf60erNc1nBGR5ew4A7N/view?usp=sharing). [Screenshot of how it looks here](https://i.imgur.com/IRTnJFt.png). Can you try them? PS: I'm surprised SO didn't suggest to go to a separate chat, is that still a thing?

Comment: My system won't let me pull the screenshots or the file hahah. Gotta love the gov

Comment: Oh, well. The image is on imgur, one of the most popular image storage sites, which is 100% safe. Just check them all at home then. :P If you have any concern with the files, upload them to virustotal.com, which scans the files with dozens of antivirus.

Comment: Due to the security systems at the office, that isn't feasible unfortunately. But its okay> I appreciate your help. The messy one I have at least works very well, as long as the most recent one is at the bottom. I'll keep researching and fussing with it. Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Right, that's why I suggested downloading them at home, so you can look at what I've done more closely and try to reproduce that at work, without bringing my files due to the security measures, of course.

Comment: Omg I totally misread that. i'm sorry. I'll look at them tonight!

Comment: Hey! I looked at it, and it works great! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great, finally!! But I wonder what was the issue before that it gave you errors?

Comment: I guess I will never know.